# Where are the MCLK and CLOCK pins in OV2640 camera?

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to connect an OV2640 camera to a Raspberry Pi Pico microcontroller.

In the manual there are pins that are called differently in the camera.
The manual has MCLK and CLOCK pins.
https://learn.adafruit.com/capturing-camera-images-with-circuitpython/raspberry-pi-pico-wiring

**What are the CLOCK and MCLK pins in the camera?**

**Do I need pull-up resistors when connecting this camera (I think not)?**

The camera has pins :
(top row) GND, SCL, SDA, D0, D2, D4, D6, DCLK, PWDN
(bottom row) +3.3, VSYNC, HREF, RST, D1, D3, D5, D7, NC

I assumed that the CLOCK pin on the Raspberry Pi Pico board should be connected to the DCLK pin on the ov2640 camera.

Pin MCLK, as it seemed to me, does not have to be connected to the camera. But I'm not sure